# Awesomium offscreen webview never load a page

Tags: c#, awesomium

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var session = WebCore.CreateWebSession(new WebPreferences { WebSecurity = false });
        var browser = WebCore.CreateWebView(1920, 3000, session, WebViewType.Offscreen);
        WebCore.ShuttingDown += WebCoreOnShuttingDown;
        browser.ConsoleMessage += BrowserOnConsoleMessage;
        browser.LoadingFrameComplete += BrowserOnLoadingFrameComplete;
        browser.DocumentReady += BrowserOnDocumentReady;
        browser.Source = new Uri("http://www.google.ru/");
        var error = browser.GetLastError();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void BrowserOnConsoleMessage(object sender, ConsoleMessageEventArgs consoleMessageEventArgs)
    {

    }

    private static void WebCoreOnShuttingDown(object sender, CoreShutdownEventArgs coreShutdownEventArgs)
    {

    }

    private static void BrowserOnDocumentReady(object sender, UrlEventArgs urlEventArgs)
    {

    }

    private static void BrowserOnLoadingFrameComplete(object sender, FrameEventArgs frameEventArgs)
    {

    }
}
```

It does not work. None of these events ever fired. `error` is `None`.
I'm sure I miss something obvious. Does the `WebView` should be additionally initialized somehow? I searched in Awesomium Wiki but didn't find any additional information.

Comment: Controls don't work that way. They should be placed on form.

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly are you sure you speak about Awesomium? According to this http://wiki.awesomium.net/general-use/introduction-to-web-views.html offscreen (i.e. without form) `WebView`'s are possible.

Comment: I am sure about controls. But WebView is not a control so i am wrong about placing on form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I made some research and found instruction [here](http://wiki.awesomium.com/tutorials/tutorial-1-hello-awesomium.html)

> Wait Until the Page Has Finished Loading
>
> while (view->IsLoading())
>   web_core->Update();

in .Net the `WebCore.Update` is deprecated and have a description:

> In a non-UI environment (or even in a UI application), you can now
>   create a dedicated Thread for Awesomium and from that thread, use 
>   WebCore.Run to start auto-updating.

so i created this code example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task t = new Task(() =>
    {
        WebCore.Initialize(new WebConfig(), true);
        WebView browser = WebCore.CreateWebView(1024, 768, WebViewType.Offscreen);
        browser.DocumentReady += browser_DocumentReady;
        browser.Source = new Uri("https://www.google.ru/");
        WebCore.Run();
    });
    t.Start();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
static void browser_DocumentReady(object sender, UrlEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("DocumentReady");
}
```

You can find more info in WebCore.Run description.

Comment: I obtain this message "Starting an update loop on a thread with an existing message loop, is not supported." using WebCore.Run(). And if don't use Run(), the WebCore is always with IsLoading to true.

Answer (score 2):

I do this & seem to work well

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     var session = WebCore.CreateWebSession(new WebPreferences { WebSecurity = false });
     using (WebView webViewBrowser = WebCore.CreateWebView(1024, 768, session, WebViewType.Offscreen))
     {
         webViewBrowser.ConsoleMessage += webViewBrowser_ConsoleMessage;
         webViewBrowser.LoadingFrameComplete += webViewBrowser_LoadingFrameComplete;

         webViewBrowser.Source = new Uri("http://www.google.ru/");

         if (WebCore.UpdateState == WebCoreUpdateState.NotUpdating) WebCore.Run();
     }
 }

 static void webViewBrowser_ConsoleMessage(object sender, ConsoleMessageEventArgs e)
 {
     Debug.Print("{0} at {1}: {2} at '{3}'", e.EventName, e.LineNumber, e.Message, e.Source);
 }

 static void webViewBrowser_LoadingFrameComplete(object sender, FrameEventArgs e)
 {
     if (!e.IsMainFrame) return;

     WebView webViewBrowser = sender as WebView;

     Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Page Title: {0}", webViewBrowser.Title));
     Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Loaded URL: {0}", webViewBrowser.Source));

     BitmapSurface surface = (BitmapSurface)webViewBrowser.Surface;
     surface.SaveToPNG("result.png", true);

     WebCore.Shutdown();
 }
```